# A for loop is stuck when trying to get a pair number (even number)

Tags: c#, loops

Here is my portion of code:

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
 int tamanoAlt = 0; int tamanoAnch = 0;
 for (int al = 0; al < 1; al++)
 {
     tamanoAlt = rnd.Next(tamMinHabAlt, tamMaxHabAlt);
     if((tamanoAlt %2 ) != 0){
        al--;
     }
 }
```

The program stops in this loop. I've tried with while/do-while loops and I get same results.

I'm trying to get a pair number randomly generated. The range between `tamMinHabAlt` and `tamMaxHabAlt` is big enought to get different pair numbers.

Comment: do you mean it never leaves the loop and you get a `StackOverflowException`?

Comment: never leaves the loop and I don't get any exception

Comment: "I'm trying to get a pair number randomly generated." - why with such strange code? What specific those number should have?

Comment: Because it is na even number, the mod operation is always 0, so as you decrement "al" and the for loop won't stop.

Comment: it must be in range of thos two integers, it must be a pair number. Sorry, but I don't know any other way to do this.

Comment: Just pick a random number satisfying your range requirement, and clear the least significant bit.

Comment: what is a pair number?

Comment: a number divisible by two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a C# guy, but I'm assuming bitwise operators are similar to those of C/C++:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int tamanoAlt = rnd.Next(tamMinHabAlt, tamMaxHabAlt) & ~1;
```

Comment: [they are](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0jg3LH) (added some prints for demonstration)

Comment: Thats a cleaner way to do it, thanks man, I'm reading about bitwise operators now.

Answer (score 0):

```
This solution will work for you.


Random rnd = new Random();
int tamanoAlt = rnd.Next(tamMinHabAlt, tamMaxHabAlt);
while(tamanoAlt % 2 != 0){
    tamanoAlt = rnd.Next(tamMinHabAlt, tamMaxHabAlt);
}
```

// tamanoAlt will be a pair number

Comment: this works, but why must I give a random value before entering the loop?

Comment: Because if you find the random number before the while loop, it will never enter and you have your answer. If it does not find it, the while loop will run until na even number is found. If you only want to generate the random numbers inside the while loop, you can set tamanoAlt = 1 instead of generating a random number before the while loop.

Comment: this has the potential (even though unlikely) to run for a very long time.

Comment: but if I don't set the number to something before loop it won't work, I don't understand why

Comment: You have to set the variable to something on declaration or you'll get a compile time error. So if you declare to the first random you'll have 50/50 chances of not entering the while loop. If you set it to an odd number you'll always enter the loop. @Default, it will not run for very long time. It will make 3/4 loops tops as every random number generated as 50/50 chances of being a even number.